# How to hide vertical scrollbar in windows OS

Tags: html, css, overflow

How to hide vertical scrollbar in windows OS when using CSS `overflow` property set to scroll. I am able to scroll but I would like to hide the vertical scroll bar.

Here is my HTML markup:

```
 <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 1000px">
      <h1>Some content...</h1>
    </div>
```

On browsing, I found that on Mac OS by default the scrollbars are hidden. Is there any such option on windows?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need.This will hide vertical scroll bar.

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

To hide horizontal, use:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-y: auto;` this will hide the vertical scrollbar by default if the content isn't full then show it when it overflows the element without the content flowing outside.

If this is what you mean by "Mac OS by default the scrollbars are hidden"?

```
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 1000px">
    <h1>Some content...</h1>
</div>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/pqovYP

(Note: This example has some changes to your code only to show a live example of this working.)

```js
var i = 0;

function add_more(node)
{
   node.parentElement.innerHTML += [
      "<h1>Some content ",
      "#", ++i,
      " ...</h1>"
   ].join("");
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 400px">
   <h1>Some content...</h1>
   <button onclick="add_more(this)">Add more content</button>
</div>
```